# One AVPlayer vs Multiple AVPlayer for each AVPlayerLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, avfoundation

I'm trying to create app like Vine. I have a collection view where each item contains a view with `AVPlayerLayer` and `AVPlayer` instance and correspondingly avplayer has been attached to layer.

Everythings work fine.

But I would like to know, maybe it will be better if I use only one `AVPlayer` instance for every `AVPlayerLayer` that contains in collection view. And if I want to show next item I'm removing the `AVPlayer` instance from current item's layer and moving it to the next item's layer. After all I call `[videoPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:newItem];`

And maybe someone know the better solution for get the same performance like Vine app.

Comment: did you ever figure out what was better?

Comment: @Eric, Yeah I have tried both, most of the time I used to play video with one AVPlayer and everything was awesome. However I had one minor problem with it (management between players, never mind). Later I refactored the code and now I'm using one player for one item and everything is okay. About 2-4 instances of AVPlayer are living at one moment.

Comment: @tikhop are you using the cell as the delegate of the player? In other words, are you assigning a cell.player type property to the cell?

Comment: @kevin definitely, the cell is a delegate of player instance, also each cell contains own player instance and when some cell want to play the player becomes active whereupon the previous player stops

Comment: Hi @tikhop, did the ratio of one `AVPlayer` to many `AVPlayerLayer` worked?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it within a collection view:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  VideoWall
//
//  Created by James Alan Bush on 6/13/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 James Alan Bush. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

static NSString *kCellIdentifier = @"Cell Identifier";

@interface ViewController () {
    dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueueLocal;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (id)initWithCollectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)layout
{
    if (self = [super initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout])
    {
        [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
        dispatchQueueLocal = dispatch_queue_create( "local session queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT );
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [self.collectionView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.width, AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.height)];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDataSource>

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.assetsFetchResults.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = (UICollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        cell.contentView.layer.sublayers = nil;
        dispatch_release(dispatchQueueLocal);
    }];
    dispatch_retain(dispatchQueueLocal);
    dispatch_async( dispatchQueueLocal, ^{
        [self drawPlayerLayerForCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    });
    [CATransaction commit];

    return cell;
}

- (void)drawPlayerLayerForCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    void (^drawPlayerLayer)(UICollectionViewCell*, NSIndexPath*) = ^(UICollectionViewCell* cell, NSIndexPath* indexPath) {
        [AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.imageManager requestPlayerItemForVideo:AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.assetsFetchResults[indexPath.item] options:nil resultHandler:^(AVPlayerItem * _Nullable playerItem, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if(![[info objectForKey:PHImageResultIsInCloudKey] boolValue]) {
                    AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem]];
                    [playerLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
                    [playerLayer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
                    [playerLayer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
                    [playerLayer setFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];

                    [cell.contentView.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
                    [(AVPlayer *)playerLayer.player play];

                } else {
                    [AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.imageManager requestImageForAsset:AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.assetsFetchResults[indexPath.item]
                                                                          targetSize:CGSizeMake(AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.flowLayout.itemSize.width, AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.flowLayout.itemSize.height)
                                                                         contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
                                                                             options:nil
                                                                       resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
                                                                           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                                               cell.contentView.layer.contents = (__bridge id)result.CGImage;
                                                                           });
                                                                       }];
                }
            });
        }];
    };
    drawPlayerLayer(cell, indexPath);
}

@end
```

The AppDelegate implementation file looks like this:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  VideoWall
//
//  Created by James Alan Bush on 6/13/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 James Alan Bush. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

+ (AppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate
{
    return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch

    self.width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width / 2.0;
    self.height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height / 4.0;

    self.window                    = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = [self viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController.view = self.viewController.view;


    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (ViewController *)viewController {
    ViewController *c = self->_viewController;
    if (!c) {
        c = [[ViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:[self flowLayout]];
        [c.view setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        self->_viewController = c;
    }
    return c;
}

- (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)flowLayout {
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *v = self->_flowLayout;
    if (!v) {
        v = [UICollectionViewFlowLayout new];
        [v setItemSize:CGSizeMake(AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.width, AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.height)];
        [v setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
        [v setMinimumLineSpacing:0.0];
        [v setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0.0];
        [v setEstimatedItemSize:CGSizeMake(AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.width, AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.height)];
        self->_flowLayout = v;
    }
    return v;
}

- (PHCachingImageManager *)imageManager {
    PHCachingImageManager *i = self->_imageManager;
    if (!i) {
        i = [[PHCachingImageManager alloc] init];
        self->_imageManager = i;
    }
    return i;
}

- (PHFetchResult *)assetsFetchResults {
    PHFetchResult *i = self->_assetsFetchResults;
    if (!i) {
        PHFetchResult *smartAlbums = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeSmartAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumVideos options:nil];
        PHAssetCollection *collection = smartAlbums.firstObject;
        if (![collection isKindOfClass:[PHAssetCollection class]])
            return nil;
        PHFetchOptions *allPhotosOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
        allPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]];
        i = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:collection options:allPhotosOptions];
        self->_assetsFetchResults = i;
    }
    return i;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

These are the only two files you need; no NIB/XIB.

Comment: Hey James! Does the cells are being deallocated or they have some kind of retain-cycle which prevents them from release?

Comment: In other words, If I scroll about 100 videos, will all of them kept in the memory or only the currently playing one?